# Need help creating a Time Gate in Twilio Function

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions

I'm new to Twilio Studio, Functions, and by extension node.js . I'm trying to create a function that will evaluate the current day and time. If that time is outside the window i want to return false, otherwise true. This is what i have so far:

```
    exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    
    var day = Twilio.Date.toString();
    twiml.say(day);
    
    callback(null, twiml);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the below Twilio Function, and modify accordingly.

```
// Time of Day Routing 
// Useful for IVR logic, for Example in Studio, to determine which path to route to
// Add moment-timezone 0.5.31 as a dependency under Functions Global Config, Dependencies

const moment = require('moment-timezone');
  
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  
  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  
  function businessHours() {
  // My timezone East Coast (other choices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)
  const now = moment().tz('America/New_York');
  
  // Weekday Check using moment().isoWeekday()
  // Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2 ... Sunday = 7 
  if(now.isoWeekday() <= 5 /* Check for Normal Work Week Monday - Friday */) {
   
    //Work Hours Check, 9 am to 5pm (17:00 24 hour Time)
    if(now.hour() >= 9 && now.hour() < 17 /* 24h basis */) {
      return true
    }
  } 
  
  // Outside of business hours, return false
  return false
  
  };
  
  const isOpen = businessHours();
    if (isOpen) {
       twiml.say("Business is Open");
    } else {
       twiml.say("Business is Closed");
    }
    callback(null, twiml);
};
```

Comment: Fwiw, `Moment.js` is end of life. Twilio suggests `Intl.DateTimeFormat()` now.  Here's an example: https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets/quickstart/time-of-day-routing