# Is my Twilio function correct for routing a call based on day of week and time of day?

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to route calls to different agents based on time of day using Twilio Studio referencing the following function and wondering if it's correct? I'm not a programmer, so this is adapted from [Need help creating a Time Gate in Twilio Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63649288/need-help-creating-a-time-gate-in-twilio-function)

```
// Time of Day Routing 
// Useful for IVR logic, for Example in Studio, to determine which path to route to
// Add moment-timezone 0.5.31 as a dependency under Functions Global Config, Dependencies

const moment = require('moment-timezone');
  
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  
  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  
  function businessHours() {
  // My timezone East Coast (other choices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)
  const now = moment().tz('America/Denver');
  
  // Weekday Check using moment().isoWeekday()
  // Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2 ... Sunday = 7 
  if(now.isoWeekday() == 1 || 3 || 5 /* Check for Normal Work Week Monday - Friday */) {
   
    //Work Hours Check, 9 am to 5pm (17:00 24 hour Time)
    if((now.hour() >= 8 && now.hour() < 9:30) || (now.hour() >= 12 && now.hour() < 17) /* 24h basis */) {
      return true
    }
  } 
  if(now.isoWeekday() == 2 /* Check for Normal Work Week Monday - Friday */) {
   
    //Work Hours Check, 9 am to 5pm (17:00 24 hour Time)
    if((now.hour() >= 8:30 && now.hour() < 11) /* 24h basis */) {
      return true
    }
  }   
  if(now.isoWeekday() == 4 /* Check for Normal Work Week Monday - Friday */) {
   
    //Work Hours Check, 9 am to 5pm (17:00 24 hour Time)
    if((now.hour() >= 8 && now.hour() < 10:30) || (now.hour() >= 15 && now.hour() < 17) /* 24h basis */) {
      return true
    }
  }   
  
  // Outside of business hours, return false
  return false
  
  };
  
  const isOpen = businessHours();
    if (isOpen) {
       twiml.say("Business is Open");
    } else {
       twiml.say("Business is Closed");
    }
    callback(null, twiml);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Stack Overflow is not the best place to ask "is this correct?". It's much better to come with an actual problem that you have and a description of the things you have tried to fix that problem. It's also hard to answer "is this correct?" if we don't know the outcome you actually want.

However, I can see one issue with the code above and that is dealing with working hours that fall outside of just on the hour tests.

`now.hour()` will return a whole number that is the current hour. You cannot compare this to `9:30` for example. Instead, we have to look at both the hours and the minutes,

In your first conditional hour check you have:

```js
    if((now.hour() >= 8 && now.hour() < 9:30) || (now.hour() >= 12 && now.hour() < 17) /* 24h basis */) {
      return true
    }
```

In words, you seem to be going for: If the time is between 8am and 9:30am or the time is between 12pm and 5pm then return true.

To cope with the time 9:30 we have to check that the time is between 8am and 10am and if it is some number of minutes past 9, that number of minutes is not more than 30. Just to cut down the code we are looking at, the issues is this predicate:

```js
(now.hour() >= 8 && now.hour() < 9:30)
```

We could replace this with:

```js
((now.hour() >= 8 && now.hour() < 9) || (now.hour() == 9 && now.minute() < 30))
```

This now tests that the hour is **more than or equal to 8** and **less than 9** *OR* that the hour is **equal to 9** and the minutes are **less than 30**.

Since "greater than or equal to 8 and less than 9" is effectively the same as "equal to 8" we could shorten this to:

```js
(now.hour() === 8 || (now.hour() == 9 && now.minute() < 30))
```

But you will want to use the full version when you want to fix further comparisons, like between 8:30 and 11 or between 8 and 10:30.

Hopefully this gives you a good idea of how to approach all your time comparisons.