# How to Split the flow based on what day it is and what time it is

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I am making an IVR and i want to split the flow based on the currently day of the week and time. for example if someone calls on Sunday when we are closed i would like it to give a different greeting than if it was Monday at noon. basically if it is currently between 8am-5pm Monday Through Friday it does down one line or if we are outside that range you go to another. is this even possable?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In order to split based on the time of day within Studio, you need to use a Twilio Function to perform the time check. Check out [this other answer which details an example function you can use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63649288/need-help-creating-a-time-gate-in-twilio-function).